# Laravel policy send 403 for update and 201 for create

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have this policy :

```
class ProjectPagePolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    public function viewAny(User $user)
    {
        return true;
    }
    public function view(User $user, ProjectPage $projectPage)
    {
        return true;
    }
    public function create(User $user)
    {
        return $user->isAdmin() || $user->isDeveloper();
    }
    public function update(User $user, ProjectPage $projectPage)
    {
        return $user->isAdmin() || $user->isDeveloper();
    }

    ..........
}
```

ProjectPageController :

```
class ProjectPageController extends Controller
{

public function __construct()
{
    $this->authorizeResource(ProjectPage::class, 'project-page');
}
public function index(Request $request)
{
    return response(
        [],
        HttpStatusCode::OK
    );
}
public function store(ProjectPageRequest $projectPageRequest)
{
    $inputs = $projectPageRequest->validated();

    $projectPage = ProjectPage::create($inputs);

    return response()->json([
        'data' => new ProjectPageResource($projectPage)
    ], HttpStatusCode::Created);
}
public function update(
    ProjectPageRequest $projectPageRequest,
    ProjectPage $projectPage
) {
    $inputs = $projectPageRequest->validated();

    $projectPage->fill($inputs)->save();

    return response(status: HttpStatusCode::NoContent);
}
```

In the routes file :

```
Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum'])->group(function () {
Route::post(
    '/refresh-token',
    fn () => app(RefreshTokenResponse::class)
);

Route::apiResources([
    'project-page'  => ProjectPageController::class,
]);
```

});

When I try to save a project page, I received 201 CREATED so all good in this case.

When I try to update it I have 403 forbidden.

Where the problem is ? Why is working on creation and not on updated ? Have an idea about that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** Remove the second argument (`'project-page'`) from your `authorizeResource` call.

---

When using `Route::resource(...)`, Laravel will convert a hyphenated route parameter to be snake-case (this will not have any affect on the URL itself, just how laravel accesses the parameter). This will mean that that when you call `authorizeResource` with `project-page`, it won't match. This will in-turn cause the `authorize` method to fail.

You can view your routes via the CLI with the following:

```
php artisan route:list
```

which should show your route param for your `project-page` routes to be `project_page` e.g. `project-page/{project_page}`